# Ruby /= or %= operator causes weird syntax coloring in VSCode

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

Whenever there is the operaotr `/=` or `%=` in Ruby code, Visual Studio Code show them in a weird coloring:

[image]

[image]

Compare them with the correct look of `+=` operator:

[image]

I tried a few other languages that supports combined assignment operators, none of them have such problems.

Is there a way to get over this issue?

Comment: Must think it's commenting, somehow?

Comment: @DaveNewton That was my guess, too. However, VSCode shows Ruby comments not the same style as other languages such as Lua or Java, either. So it's hard to tell exactly. Possibly they have the same root cause.

Comment: In your first example, visual studio probably thinks that everything after the first `/` is a regular expression, and probably thinks that you are trying to pass a string to `num` in the second example (`%=abcde=` is the same as `"abcde"`. So if you can edit the way that visual studio's syntax highlighter parses ruby you should be able to fix this

Answer (score 1):

You could fix this problem by edit the file `resources/app/plugins/vs.language.ruby/rubyDef.js`. Comment the line 230 as followings:

```js
[/:'/, { token: 'string.s.delim', bracket: '@open', next: '@sstring.s' }],
/* --COMMENT THIS LINE-- ['/', { token: 'regexp.delim', bracket: '@open', next: '@regexp' }],*/
[/[{}()\[\]]/, '@brackets'],
```

This may cause some error in regex highlighting. We need to wait for Microsoft to fix the bug for long term solution.